# How can I insert this on my table?

Tags: python, sql, insert

Creating my table:

```
 cursor.execute("""
   CREATE TABLE if not exists intraday_quote (
   id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
   symbol VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
   date DATE,
   time DATE,
   open FLOAT,
   high FLOAT,
   low FLOAT,
   close FLOAT,
   volume INTEGER);
   """)
```

and I`m trying to insert this:

```
    conn = sqlite3.connect('intraday_quote.db')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    # Prepare SQL query to INSERT a record into the database.
    sql = """INSERT INTO intraday_quote(symbol) VALUES ('Mac123432')"""
    cursor.execute(sql)
```

No insertion happened in the database. What I am missing?

Comment: What error are you getting? Can you paste that?

Comment: No error, I can get on the method, but the code isnt insert on the table.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 3):

You need to commit your changes so they can get into effect in database.
commit all db operations like update, insert.

```
cursor.commit()
```

after your execute is succeeded. You can get return of the `cursor.execute`. If it is not `None` then you can try committing the changes else use `rollback`(exercise for you :) ) so you wont end up with wrong data updated in database.

Comment: Where just about so say the same, you need to close it as well.


conn.close()

Comment: THANKS A LOT.  I FORGOT THIS.   conn.comit()  works   <3

Answer (score 2):

You need to do `conn.commit()` to see the changes in the database. Quoting the [**documentation**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.commit)

> This method commits the current transaction. If you don’t call this method, anything you did since the last call to commit() is not visible from other database connections. If you wonder why you don’t see the data you’ve written to the database, please check you didn’t forget to call this method.

Comment: THANKS A LOT.  I FORGOT THIS.   conn.comit()  works   <3